# MacBook Pro Dual Boot Snow Leopard and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, multi-boot

what are the best guides out there to do this. just got a MBP today (my first mac) and I'm a complete noob with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use Boot Camp to do this.

Try this guide [here](http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/01/15/using-boot-camp-to-install-windows-7-on-your-mac-the-complete-walkthrough/).

Comment: Have no fear. It works expremely well. My two gripes are that there are no drivers for te ambient light sensor provided which means win7 won't do adaptive display dimming. This is mitigated by the bootcamp display brightness controlls which work just like OS X. The gripe is Apple doesn't provide a driver for the Infineon TPM which means Bitlocker can't use the TPM.